# Sockets in Swift (Not webSocket)

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, client-side

I want to build a special chat app and I'm building my server side in Python.
In Python I use the library Sockets, and Threading..

I tried to find a library of sockets in Swift to build a the client-side (the mobile app) and all I could find is that websocket libraries and this is not what I want, I need a simple socket library, like I have in python import sockets.

so the question is: how can I create a client-side to a **socket** communication and not **websocket** ? I just could not find an implement of sockets in Swift

Comment: Have you tried with [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) or [SwiftWebSocket](https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket)?

Comment: I especially write that I DON'T want to use websocket @EnriqueBermúdez

Comment: @AdamAohenHillel your original question saids that you didn't want to use Socket.io, DOESN'T said that you didn't want to use web sockets..

Comment: You right, I change the question to be the right way, Sorry.

Comment: Here is a sockets library that you can use: [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket). It supports both TCP and UDP protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets library that use to communicate by sockets:
https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket
Thanks for @Enrique Bermúdez